# Split string into substrings on one or more whitespaces

Tags: regex, string, r, split

I want to split a string into several substrings at those positions where one or more whitespaces (tab, space,...) occur. [In the documentation of `strsplit()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/strsplit.html) it says, that split is interpreted as a regular expression.

Thus i tried the following, which did not work:

```
test = "123 nnn      dddddd"
strsplit(test, "[:space:]+")
```

it only returned:

```
[[1]]
[1] "123 nnn      dddddd"
```

but should return:

```
[[1]]
[1] "123" "nnn" "dddddd"
```

Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: Try this instead: `strsplit(test , "[ ]+")`

Comment: actually `strsplit(test , " +")` works as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
strsplit(test, '\\s+')
[[1]]
[1] "123"    "nnn"    "dddddd"
```

`\\s` will match all the whitespace characters.

Comment: I wish I had put my comment as an answer now!! :)

Answer (score 7):

`[:space:]` must be placed inside a character class `[]` to make it works, i.e. `[[:space:]]`. `[:space:]` on its own will be interpreted as a character class consisting of `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c`, `e`.

```
strsplit(test, "[[:space:]]+")
```

Note that by default `strsplit` will use POSIX ERE, which results in **locale-dependent** interpretation of `[:space:]`.

In PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression), `[:space:]` is **locale-independent** and is equivalent to `\p{Xps}`. Therefore, you might want to enable `perl` flag if you want consistent behavior across different locales.

If you only want to collapse all spaces (ASCII 32) and want to leave the horizontal tabs `\t` and new line characters `\n` alone, OR you can assume that the text contains only space (ASCII 32) as spacing character:

```
strsplit(test, " +")
```