# Splitting a string at different indexes in R

Tags: r, string

I have a string with different indexes for where there are spaces followed by digits. I want to use these indexes to split the string between them.

For example I have a vector

```
"               4 1   138  138  138  138  140  140  140  140  140  141  142  144  144  145  145  146  145  145  145  145  145  139  135  133   3391"
```

and want to split it into

```
[1]"4" "1 " "138" "138" "138" "138" "140" "140" "140" "140" "140" "141" "142" "144" 
[15]"144" "145" "145" "146" "145" "145" "145" "145" "145" "139" "135" "133 ""3391"
```

I used grepexpr(" [1-9]",data) and got

```
[[1]]
 [1]  15  17  21  26  31  36  41  46  51  56  61  66  71  76  81  86
 [17]  91  96 101 106 111 116 121 126 131 136 142
attr(,"match.length")
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
attr(,"useBytes")
 [1] TRUE
```

And I've tried to use strsplit and substr but nothing is working so far.
I get an integer error when using substr and then strsplit returns the same string.

Comment: I was trying to use the results from the `grepexpr` as the indexes to split the text

Comment: so split on whitespace? `strsplit(string, '\\s+')` like [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273766/split-string-into-substrings-on-one-or-more-whitespaces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been mentioned in the comments that you can use `strsplit()`.  Another option that would work very well on this string is `scan()`.

```
x <- "               4 1   138  138  138  138  140  140  140  140  140  141  142  144  144  145  145  146  145  145  145  145  145  139  135  133   3391"
scan(text = x, what = "")
# Read 27 items
#  [1] "4"    "1"    "138"  "138"  "138"  "138"  "140"  "140"  "140"  "140" 
# [11] "140"  "141"  "142"  "144"  "144"  "145"  "145"  "146"  "145"  "145" 
# [21] "145"  "145"  "145"  "139"  "135"  "133"  "3391"
```

The above gives us character results, as you show are desired in your question.  We can also return numeric results by leaving out the `what` argument or changing it to `integer()` (depending on the input).

```
scan(text = x)
# Read 27 items
#  [1]    4    1  138  138  138  138  140  140  140  140  140  141  142  144
# [15]  144  145  145  146  145  145  145  145  145  139  135  133 3391
```

And you can leave out the `Read 27 items` message by using `quiet = TRUE`.

One advantage of using `scan()` here is that you will not get an empty character string at the beginning of the result like you would if you used `strsplit()`.

```
strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]][1:3]
# [1] ""  "4" "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be overkill but I like `strapplyc` from `gsubfn`

For your problem, you do

```
strapplyc(x, " ([0-9]+)", simplify = T)
```

Works like the apply family but looking for the regex in parenthesis and extracting only the bits that are enclosed by `()`.